# Why RollingWithAdditionalBatch strategy is ignored during environment update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

We are using [eb_deployer](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer) which under the hood uses ElasticBeanstalk Ruby Aws Sdk. The [`Aws::ElasticBeanstalk::Client#update_environment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ElasticBeanstalk/Client.html#update_environment-instance_method) method is used in particular to trigger a deployment. I'm trying to make use of `RollingWithAdditionalBatch` deployment policy however this settings seems to be ignored when the environment update is initiated via mentioned sdk method.

Inside of `option_settings` parameter of `update_environment` we have:

```
{
    "namespace"=>"aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
    "option_name"=>"DeploymentPolicy",
    "value"=>"RollingWithAdditionalBatch"
},
```

However despite the above the deployment is using Rolling strategy as far as I can tell:

```
2017-01-11 15:59:42 UTC+0100    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
2017-01-11 15:59:42 UTC+0100    INFO    Successfully deployed new configuration to environment.
2017-01-11 15:59:42 UTC+0100    INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
2017-01-11 15:58:32 UTC+0100    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2017-01-11 15:57:57 UTC+0100    INFO    Updating environment ENV_ID configuration settings.
```

You can find the details of the method call in the [update-environment-call.txt](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/files/726149/update-environment-call.txt).

After some more tests it turned out that the issue might not necessarily be related to [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby).
The following invocation:

```
client.update_environment(
         environment_id:"ENV_ID",
         version_label:"backend.1762",
         option_settings:[{
            "namespace"=>"aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
            "option_name"=>"DeploymentPolicy",
            "value"=>"RollingWithAdditionalBatch"
         },{
            "namespace"=>"aws:ec2:vpc",
            "option_name"=>"VPCId",
            "value"=>"VPC_ID_ABC"
         }]
)
```

Triggers **Rolling** deployment.

However if we remove the VPC setting then **Rolling with additional batch** is invoked as requested:

```
client.update_environment(
         environment_id:"ENV_ID",
         version_label:"backend.1762",
         option_settings:[{
            "namespace"=>"aws:elasticbeanstalk:command",
            "option_name"=>"DeploymentPolicy",
            "value"=>"RollingWithAdditionalBatch"
         }]
)
```

Between subsequent calls to `update_environment` the only parameter that has different value is `version_label`.

#### Steps to reproduce the problem:

Step 1. We call update_environment with `version_label: 1` and certain `option_settings`. The option_settings include `RollingWithAdditionalBatch` but also have other settings i.e. `VPCId`. The environment is updated properly and the `RollingWithAdditionalBatch` shows up as a configured value in AWS Web Console.

Step 2,3,4,5,... We call `update_environment` with `version_label: n` and **the same** `option_settings` as in Step 1. The new version of application is deployed using **Rolling** strategy which in my view is unexpected.

However if we perform Step 2,3,5 and in `option_settings` provide only a single option for `RollingWithAdditionalBatch` then the new version is deployed correctly using `RollingWithAdditionalBatch`.

#### Did somebody encounter this behaviour and knows how to work around it?

*[Related Github Issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1394)*

*[Related AWS Forum Post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246902&tstart=0)*

Answer (score 1):

As noted by AWS Support

Here are some important excerpts from our conversation with aws support so that people having the same problem as we do can find it (emphasis mine):

> As (...) mentioned, this behaviour occurred because the changes you made resulted in **a configuration update** being triggered. The deployment strategy used by a configuration change is different to that used by an application deployment. Certain modifications will trigger a configuration update, and some of these changes will require that your environment's instances be replaced (though some will not). Importantly, **a configuration update can be triggered even if the configuration option has not been changed since the last `update_environment` call.**

So it turns out that the behavior, while poorly documented if at all is how the elastic beanstalk is supposed to work.

In order to overcome it's best to supply empty `option_settings` to be sure that the `update_environment` triggers Application Deployment like so:

```
client.update_environment(
         environment_id:"ENV_ID",
         version_label:"new_version_of_app",
         option_settings:[]
)
```

Comment: This sounds exactly like our situation.  We recently changed our EB Deploy pipeline to set environment variables using `option_settings` and ever since then we noticed the deploys changed to `rolling` from `rolling with additional batch`.  Thanks for sharing this.